# tooltip responsive inside a div - not showing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to insert a d3 chart on a div in html but Tootlip is not working or not showing in html. what am I doing wrong?

[code](https://plnkr.co/edit/GLyA70V4X7xqhg06mgMF?p=preview)

```
<div id="mainTooltip" class="hidden">
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further? The tooltip appears to be working just fine, do you want the tooltip to be visible somewhere at all time?

Comment: yes, I insert this d3.js in a HTML with different div. The tooltip is not showing. The tooltip should to be visible somewhere on a pie chart at all time.

Comment: delete? @RobertAndersson

Comment: The tooltip position got mixed up with the additional tooltip that I added, will give you a better answer when I have time

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new div and wrapped your code in another div so all positions stay relative to eachother

The only new code I had to add was this:

```
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {

      d3.select("#centerTooltip")
        .classed("hidden", false)
        .html(d.data.str_lab + "<br />" + d.data.num);
  })
```

And in the div wrapper css I added:

```
#all {
  margin:auto;
  width: 700px;
}
```

To make sure that everything aligns properly.

Here's a fork of your code: [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/sSITuaI2ErWJjdlDbQIQ?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, i understand it which is the reason why my other diagram use with v4. This diagram uses v3. this is why it disturbs.

Comment: @joooo If you want to upgrade to v4 I'd sugest looking through the [Changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) to the relevant parts that needs to be changed.